# Creating OWIN middleware in .NET standard

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, owin

**TL;DR;**

Is there a way to create an Owin middleware in .NET Standard that will be compatible backward with Microsoft.Owin?

**Details**

I created a simple middleware like:

```
public class RequestTrackingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestTrackingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        await _next(context);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(sw);
    }
```

I added it in "classic" ASP.NET app with Owin on the board. Using:

```
public override void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use<FinaiRequestTrackingMiddleware>();
}
```

But I end up with:

> No conversion available between Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.IdentityFactoryMiddleware`2[....] and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegate.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just extract the code in the `Invoke` method and create two variants of the `RequestTrackingMiddleware` class, one for each version of Owin.

Comment: @DavidG if I don't find a solution I will end with exactly this. But I was hoping that .NET standard will solve such #if in code

Comment: I don't think it's an issue with .Net standard, I think it's the different variants of Owin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can but that's not OWIN middleware, that's ASP.NET Core middleware. See this blog post http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-write-owin-middleware-in-5-different-steps (step 3 is the  most relevant). You can then use that OWIN middleware in Katana or ASP.NET Core (via the OWIN bridge) see https://codeopinion.com/migrate-from-katana-asp-net-core/ as an example.